# Error while running weka3.8.0 package manager

Tags: java, weka

when i am running weka.jar 3.8.0 (gui on mac) in tools>Package Manager it shows error... "There was a problem establishing the package meta data cache.We'll try to use the repository directly." and the error shows like that

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1148)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:989)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:986)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2662)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$300(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$12.run(HttpURLConnection.java:2575)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$12.run(HttpURLConnection.java:2573)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2572)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1770)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1433)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1431)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getRepositoryPackageMetaDataOnlyAsZipLegacy(DefaultPackageManager.java:1037)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getRepositoryPackageMetaDataOnlyAsZip(DefaultPackageManager.java:1010)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.refreshCache(WekaPackageManager.java:1560)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.establishCacheIfNeeded(WekaPackageManager.java:1385)
at weka.gui.PackageManager$EstablishCache.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:280)
at weka.gui.PackageManager$EstablishCache.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:247)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I try to google some methods to solve that but seems not work....

Answer (score 1):

From the Exception it seems like there is no answer from the repository.

It could be one of the following:

1. The repository is down - try to connect later. You can validate that by trying to connect from another place.
2. Something is blocking your communication - check your Internet connection and firewall.
3. The way you tried to connect directly to the repository is wrong - make sure you are doing it right.